# Network ACL association to subnet in nondefault VPC at the time of acl creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cli

i am trying to set up a new VPC from scratch using aws cli.
The VPC infrastructure that i require needs various subnets and Network ACLs associated to them. The Network ACLs that i am creating are not associated to any subnet by default, as it is a *non default VPC, so default associations are not in place.* This situation brings me two scenarios :

1. **Associate a Network ACL to a subnet at the time of creation of Network ACL-**
   The create-network-acl aws cli command doesn't support it.
2. **Replace the old subnet association-**
   To replace a subnet association i need to have an old association id. As explained earlier, there are no subnet association already present so there is no past association to replace with.

Is there any work around solution to this problem, or does aws cli support case 1, is there any command for it.

Comment: which requirement from stack overflow guideline is it is not fulfulling. care to explain !

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution for this problem? I am also trying the same using AWS CLI -- I created a subnet and an ACL but I can't associate them unfortunately... @subham

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite new to AWS and I also had the task to do it. How I achieved it:

```
# get both resource and client
ec2 = boto3.resource( 'ec2' )
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2' )

# associating an ACL with a subnet is a mess:
# 1) create your own ACL
# 2) all subnets are connected to a default ACL - find this ACL
# 3) get all the association IDs of this connection
# 4) call replace_network_acl_association with your own ACL ID

# create the ACL in your vpc
networkACL = ec2.create_network_acl( VpcId = vpc.id )

# get default ACL
response = ec2_client.describe_network_acls( NetworkAclIds=[], Filters=[] )

# get association IDs
myAssociations = []
for acl in response['NetworkAcls']:
    if( acl["VpcId"] == vpc.id and len( acl['Associations'] ) > 0 ):
        myAssociations = acl['Associations']
        break

# replace them to our ACL
for a in myAssociations:
    ec2_client.replace_network_acl_association(
        AssociationId = a['NetworkAclAssociationId'],
        NetworkAclId = networkACL.id
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CLI to build up a complex stack is a really low level solution, I wouldn't recommend to do that. 
I would create a cloudformation stack. It can be a fix stack or a more generic one with input parameters. You can easily test it manually and if it works well, then you can integrate it to your application by calling the create Cloudformation via the CLI.

Comment: ya i understand what u said but my requirement compels me to use aws cli. can  u put some suggestions on that . thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What I see is the best way from CLI or APIs (such as BOTO3) is to re-associate the subnet. Initially when the Subnet is created, it is associated to the default VPC ACL. Then you can re-associate it to the right ACL yourself.